# How to use Z3 C++ API to prove a theory based on input parameter?

Tags: c++, z3, smt

I am trying to use the Z3 C++ API to achieve the following:

```
(set-option :produce-proofs true)

(declare-const Weight Int)
(declare-const WeightLimit Int)
(declare-const P1 Bool)

(assert (= WeightLimit 10))

(assert (= P1 (>= Weight WeightLimit)))
(assert (= P1 true))

;Facts - Input
(assert (= Weight 100))

(check-sat)
```

And I ended up to the following function:

```
void test() {
    try {        
        context ctx;        
        Z3_string str = "(declare-const Weight Int) (declare-const WeightLimit Int) (declare-const P1 Bool) (assert (= WeightLimit 10)) (assert (= P1 (>= Weight WeightLimit))) (assert (= P1 true)) (assert (= Weight 100)) (check-sat)"; //Generated by some other function
        expr fs(ctx, Z3_parse_smtlib2_string(Z3_context(ctx), str, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));

        solver s(ctx);
        s.add(fs);

        switch (s.check()) {
            case unsat:   std::cout << "not satisfied\n"; break;
            case sat:     std::cout << "satisfied\n"; break;
            case unknown: std::cout << "unknown\n"; break;
        } 

        model m = s.get_model();
        std::cout << m << "\n";

    }
    catch (z3::exception e) {
        std::cout << e.msg() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to pass the Weight value as input parameter to the function instead of having it hard-coded?

Furthermore, how can I set-option by using the Z3 C++ API? And what is the impact if I don't set the option?

Comment: I am expecting if `Weight` is passed with value 9, the theory that `(assert (= P1 (>= Weight WeightLimit)))` should not be satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this needs to be handled by the function that generates that string as its output, the one you commented as *"//Generated by some other function"*

You'd simply pass the `Weight` as a parameter to that function, which should use the correct value in generating the string.

If that function is *not* available to you for whatever reason, you'll have to do some string-processing; but of course that would be extremely brittle and error-prone.

The other alternative would be to *not* pass a string, but rather use the API to actually assert facts one at a time; but from your description it seems that's probably not a choice for you either.